# Unable to run google calendar java api sample

Tags: java, api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to run the google calendar api sample provided by google found here

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3

I'm runnig the calendar-cmdline-sample

I copy the client_secrets.json in place with my data but when I run the sample I get this error :

```
   jun 05, 2014 4:38:09 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory     setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
    WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody:   C:\Users\simon.cigoj\.store\calendar_sample
    jun 05, 2014 4:38:09 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
    WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner:   C:\Users\simon.cigoj\.store\calendar_sample
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/component/LifeCycle
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at   com.google.api.services.samples.calendar.cmdline.CalendarSample.authorize(CalendarSample.java:98)
        at com.google.api.services.samples.calendar.cmdline.CalendarSample.main(CalendarSample.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.component.LifeCycle
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: The error is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/component/LifeCycle`, which means it can't find/load a class.

Comment: @DavidRTribble of course, but the added libs are all in the build path, and i've followed the instructions to run this example...it sould be straight foreward but it looks like it sholud be twiked a little ... I didn't have time to digg further

Comment: Have you added any other code to the project? I've never head of that package before.

Answer (score 0):

Adding following maven dependency fixes run time errors

org.mortbay.jetty
  jetty-util
  6.1.26